# Table is not taking up entire height of page

Tags: html, css, firefox

So, I'm trying to make a table take up the entire browser window with width and height.

I also want the table cells to be of EQUAL size.

It's not working.  Currently, it fits the WIDTH of the window, but not the height.  I've tried setting table height to 100%, but it does not work (at least in Firefox).  This is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css"/>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td>
</tr>

</table>

</html>
```

And this is the css:

```
table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1;
}

tr{
    height:100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Both answers below with the html, body {} CSS are correct. The fiddle will show it. Don't just set the body, but also include the html as they mention so the entire document takes up the viewport height.

Comment: Also as I said, you should remove tr's height for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

CSS

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;


}

table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    border:1;
}

tr{
    height:auto;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.  As soon as the thing times out I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your `body` and `html` also be the 100% of the window: Add this on the CSS

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/ASVpD/3/**

To make all your row equals remove the `height:100%` form `tr`

```
tr{
  /*height:100%;*/ Remove this
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try also this:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Also remove tr {height:100%}

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y73bT/2/

Also you may use short doctype:  instead of that.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm trying to get this to work in firefox, and so I cutted and pasted that into my .css file.  The result was the first row was elongated while the rows below it were small.  I need all of the rows to be of equal size.  Let me edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: That is simple: just remove tr height

Comment: Updated answer and fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Set the table position to absolute and then set the position of each edge:

```
table { width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

table height is relative to its parent. Set html and body to height: 100% and remove height: 100% from tr:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
}
table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1;
}
tr{
    background-color:blue;
}
```